# Merge all json files in a directory nodejs

Tags: json, node.js

I would like to merge all json files in a directory in nodejs. The files are being uploaded by user and all i]I know is their names are device"count".json. Count being incrememented each time. I know of json-concat but how do I use it to merge all files in a directory?

```
    jsonConcat({
    src: [],
    dest: "./result.json"
}, function (json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if You read [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-concat) carefully You'll see this part:

> The options object passed may have the following keys:
>
> ```
> src:
>     (String) path pointing to a directory
>     (Array) array of paths pointing to files and/or directories
>     defaults to . (current working directory)
>     Note: if this is a path points to a single file, nothing will be done.
> ```

so here is fix:

1) move json files to some concrete path.

2) check this code:

```
jsonConcat({
    src: './path/to/json/files',
    dest: "./result.json"
}, function (json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

and [here is the prove how it uses src param](https://github.com/GochoMugo/json-concat/blob/master/src/json-concat.coffee#L81)

Mostly it needs from developer not just to use 3-rd part packages, but also dive into it's sources.

in short: KISS (:

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `fs` modules to read the files in a directory and then pass them to `json-concat`.

```
const jsonConcat = require('json-concat');
const fs = require('fs');

// an array of filenames to concat
const files = [];

const theDirectory = __dirname; // or whatever directory you want to read
fs.readdirSync(theDirectory).forEach((file) => {
  // you may want to filter these by extension, etc. to make sure they are JSON files
  files.push(file);
})

// pass the "files" to json concat
jsonConcat({
  src: files,
  dest: "./result.json"
}, function (json) {
  console.log(json);
});
```